# python tkinter drag and drop within brackets the path

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm staring with `tkinter` and I want to create an input box where you can drag and drop a file to get the path. However, when I drop the file, the path is shown between brackets, e.g {A:path to file.txt} How can I avoid the brackets to be inserted? In addition, How can I make the input box wider?

```
master = TkinterDnD.Tk()
tk.Label(master, text="Input raster:").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master, text="Output:").grid(row=1)

e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

tk.Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)
tk.Button(master, text='Show', command=ensayo).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)

e1.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
e1.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', lambda e: e1.insert(tk.END, e.data))

e2.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
e2.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', lambda e: e2.insert(tk.END, e.data))

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. It seem to occur (only), if there are spaces in the path. In this case tcl adds some curly brackets. Since this happens somewhere within tcl/tkdnd, the only ideas I have are either, changing the file path or remove the curly brackets afterwards:

```
    if file_path[0] == '{' and file_path[-1] == '}':
            file_path=file_path[1:-1]
```

Comment: You can simply call `.strip('{}')` on the path to remove leading `{` and trailing `}` if any.